# Word JS API: Range.compareLocationWith not working

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm trying to determine if the user has clicked in another paragraph.
My approach: The former selected paragraph gets stored locally as a Range object to be compared with later, when another click happens.

This is the code to get the selected paragraph:

```
export const getSelectedParagraphRange = async () => {
  return await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const range = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
      .getRange()

    return range
  })
}
```

This is the code to compare the ranges:

```
export const isParagraphStillActive = async (range: Word.Range) => {
  return await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const newRange = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
      .getRange()

    const compare = range.compareLocationWith(newRange)
    await context.sync()

    return compare.value === 'Equal'
  })
}
```

If I compare the newRange with itself it works (I get a compare object with value "Equal").
But if I compare the parameter range with itself it doesn't work (the function just "stops" without throwing an error etc).

So my guess is that the range objects which should be compared have to be taken directly from inside the function? If so, then I'm wondering how I can compare a former selected paragraph with a new one?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to studying the mentioned Building Office Add-ins book I managed to get the paragraph comparison work. The getSelectedParagraphRange function lacked the tracking of the range object by calling range.track(). Additionally the tracked ranges have to be untracked when setting a new paragraph as the current one.
(I simply wasn't aware of the principles behind the isolated context scopes).

Here's the working code:

```
export const getSelectedParagraphRange = async (formerRange?: Word.Range) => {
  return await Word.run(async (context) => {
    if (formerRange) {
      formerRange.untrack()
      await context.sync()
    }

    const range = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
      .getRange()
    range.track()
    await context.sync()

    return range
  })
}

export const isParagraphStillActive = async (range: Word.Range) => {
  return await Word.run(range, async (context) => {
    const newRange = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
      .getRange()

    const compare = range.compareLocationWith(newRange)
    await context.sync()

    return compare.value === 'Equal'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `range` object to the overload of `Word.run` that takes an object as the first parameter.

```
export const isParagraphStillActive = async (range: Word.Range) => {
  return await Word.run(range, async (context) => {
    const newRange = context.document
     .getSelection()
     .paragraphs.getFirst()
     .getRange()

    const compare = range.compareLocationWith(newRange)
    await context.sync()

    return compare.value === 'Equal'
  })
}
```

See [Word.run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview#word-word-run-function(2)). I also recommend the book [Building Office Add-ins](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins) for advanced scenarios like this one.

Comment: Ok I added the range object as parameter to the Word.run function, but it still doesn't work.

I noticed that as soon as I try to "use" the range object inside Word.run (e.g. call range.load('text')), the function just stops. Set some console.logs to check this.

Also, the objects seem to have different attributes so I assume they still don't share the same request context. E.g. newRange has an "_IsTracked: true" property that range is missing.

Thanks for mentioning the Building Office Add-ins book. Guess I'll have to give it a shot.